# How to make the ACF editable with a front end view

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm making a website and the client wants to edit titles, contents, img,... directly with the front end view to see the changes. What is the best way to do it ?

I need something like ACF's flexible content to add a section, then a way to edit the acf field with the front end view of the site.

I looked for elementor and gutenberg but i don't know if is it the best solution, i dont want a block editor, i already have my design and the client just need to edit it seeing directly the change.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Admin panel is frontend. Can you onfigure a user/role to access only relevant sections of the admin panel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.